# two php objects, use function from the other? object variable scope?

Tags: php, function, object

Maybe I've lost it, but what am I doing wrong here? I get undefined variable 'database' when I call the route method...

```
class database {
    function connect() {
        echo("connecting database");
    }
}

class router {
    function route() {
        $database->connect();
        echo("then do some routing");
    }
}

$database = new database;
$router = new router;

$router->route();
```

- Shouldn't the reference to the $database object in the $router object fall back to the global one??
- Do I really have to pass the database object when I call the route method?
- What if the database object ends up having heaps of methods, will I be passing all of them whenever I call the route method?

Answer (score 0):

The class router can not see variable $database, you could pass it by parameter when calling the function

```
    class router {
        function route($database) {
            $database->connect();
            echo("then do some routing");
        }
    }

    $database = new database;
    $router = new router;

$router->route($database);
```

or maybe you could define $database as a global variable

```
class router {
    function route() {
        global $database;
        $database->connect();
        echo("then do some routing");
    }
}

$database   = new database;
$router = new router;

$router->route();
```

Comment: does the first solution make a 'copy' of the database object? if so, and I had an object variable as a db connection, would it create a second connection to the database?

Comment: yes it will make a copy of it. When you create an object $database you will not connect database. You will connect database when calling connect function.